# How to sample a path randomly and uniformly?

Tags: graph-theory, finite-group-theory

How to ***randomly and uniformly*** sample a path from the node 1 to arbitrary given node, say v (1<=v<=60), on the following Cayley graph --- although it is directed, please look it is a undirected graph.

[image]

Comment: What I want is merely a method with well clear explanation or references, instead of a code-description. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a random shortest path or any random path? In the latter case, is the path required to be simple?

Comment: Yes, I concern the latter case, and the path required to be simple.  Would you please give me some advices? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Even counting the number of possible paths takes exponential complexity. So I can only think of some recursive solution that essentially reduces to precalculating the number of paths for each path prefix and choosing the next vertex to move to based on the number of paths for the prefix. The graph might be too big for it to work but it is worth a try. Also, you could try to reduce the search space using the symmetries of the graph.